# `pod spec lint` validates 2 pod specs when only one exists.

Tags: ios, cocoapods

From within my pod's folder, I type `pod spec lint myPod`, the validation occurs as normal.

However, when I type `pod spec lint`, 2 validations are performed.  One is for the pod spec that in in the folder, and the other validation is for an older version that does not even exist.  In fact, the validation for the older version even shows errors inside `.m` files that no longer exist.

I've deleted the folder from my machine and started over by creating  anew pod with the same name.  And the old results show up in the line.

Why am I getting validation results from older versions?